# Efficient way to browse header definitions

Tags: c, ubuntu, header

As an example: on my system (Ubuntu 10.04), the sockaddr structure is defined in /bits/sockaddr.h as

```
struct sockaddr{
    _SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_); /*...*/
    char sa_data[14];  /*...*/
};
```

and similarly for sockaddr_in, with first field name sin_.

However, all the examples I see access the field sin_

```
structure_name.sin_family
```

I meant to track down the typedef (?) for completeness, followed included headers and such, but failed (I got to sa_family_t and similar).

As a more general question: is there, say, a searchable online source where you can simply search for where a macro or typedef is in the header files - either for a particular Ubuntu distribution, or more generically for 'typical' Linux installations? Or, obviously, a clever way from within Ubuntu's shell; or some description of how to be more efficient doing this any other idea.

Comment: Sorry, but I've not come across something as beautiful as say, the jQuery API Browser. Hopefully the 'Ubuntu Manpage' @ http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/netdevice.7.html, for example, might suffice. Also for stuff like the `struct sockaddr{`, you might like to check out the Linux Kernel API Browser (or something similar) as that belongs to standard Linux networking protocol headers.

Comment: @evandrix: why don't you post that as answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, evan. Please pardon my ignorance: when I read what you suggested, I took "Linux Kernel API browser" as the name for a tool/software that allows you to visualize or search the Linux Kernel API. But I don't seem to be able to google it successfully, nor find it in the software center or playing with apt-cache. Is it an insider's name for something else, or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the link:

> [LXR / The Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/)

done...i'll get you the reference for the Linux Kernel API Browser later (used to be able to find it online somewhere). There's the [Linux Kernel Archives](http://www.kernel.org/) for the actual source code, which you probably could generate documentation from anyways.

> Sorry, but I've not come across something as beautiful as say, the
>   jQuery API Browser. Hopefully the 'Ubuntu Manpage' @
>   manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/netdevice.7.html, for example,
>   might suffice. Also for stuff like the struct sockaddr{, you might
>   like to check out the Linux Kernel API Browser (or something similar)
>   as that belongs to standard Linux networking protocol headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: http://www.google.com/codesearch perhaps?